# Resetting the file pointer in JAVA file handling

Tags: java, file-handling

Hi All I'm pretty new to java and decided to write a voting app and make use of jdbc and file handling.
I seem have problems bringing the file pointer back to the ***starting*** of the file and upon using ***mark*** and ***reset*** it returns an error called "Mark Invalid" even though it returns ***markSupported*** as true. The following is a snippet of my code.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Voting_App {
    static Connection con;
    static Statement crsr;
    static BufferedReader br;
    static Writer fw;
    static File f;
    static FileInputStream fstream;
    static {
        try {
            fw= new FileWriter("posts.txt",true);
            fstream = new FileInputStream("posts.txt");
            br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vote","root","root");
            crsr= con.createStatement();
            f= new File("posts.txt");
        
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    static void disp_post() throws IOException {
        br.mark(0);
        String line;
        int i=1;
        if (f.length()!=0) {
            while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(i+"."+line);
                i++;
            }
        br.reset();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("There no posts currently");
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: also if there other good coding practices that im not using please point them out. Thank you

Comment: How come everything in your Voting_App is static? And I would use camel case for classes, so use VotingApp instead, like all the other classes within your class

Comment: your buffer is empty, what are you marking with `mark(0)` and no need to write `if (f.length()!=0) {` if it will not find the file will throw `NPE` what is the purpose of `i`? and why all `closeable` classes are static?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz i wasnt using any other java file or class so i didnt find a reason to create objects when i could write with everything kept as static

Comment: @emotionlessbananas how is it empty? when its prints all the posts the first time i call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the link to RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Here to reset the file pointer you can simply use
`seek(0)`
in your code.
also if you want you can get current pointer location using
`getFilePointer()`.

Comment: Please if possible correct the format. I tried my best with the format sorry if the format wrongs anyone.

Comment: Ah yes this is actually similar to Python's file handling Ill try it out and let you know ASAP

Comment: yeah please try, I had used it earlier so i just suggested you this.

Comment: lt works perfectly thanks for suggesting this solution now i can sleep in peace XD